# Click to play YT video and hide div

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, youtube, youtube-api

Not my first post here but lost login credentials so starting again.

What I need to achieve is to combine some raw Javascript with JQuery. I have a YouTube video (iframe) and my customer wants this overlayed with a div with HTML content, then on click of an image within the overlayed div play the video and hide the overlayed div.

Here is what I have so far.

```
<iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/6TgyvSQlJtI?wmode=transparent&enablejsapi=1&rel=0&autohide=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen id="video"></iframe>

$( document ).ready(function() {
$('#education-graphic').click(function() {
    $('#video-content-overlay').fadeOut('fast');
}); 
$('#video-back').click(function() {
    $('#video-content-overlay').fadeIn('fast');
}); 
});


var player;
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
player = new YT.Player('video', {
events: {
'onReady': onPlayerReady
}
});
}
function onPlayerReady(event) {
var playButton = document.getElementById("education-graphic");
playButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
player.playVideo();
});
var pauseButton = document.getElementById("video-back");
pauseButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
player.pauseVideo();
});
}
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/player_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
```

The problem is on the ipad where the two click events are attached to the same element, so I need some way of either hiding and showing the div with raw js or playing and pausing the video with jquery.

Yep, I know JQuery is JS, but I am having problems getting this to work.

Cheers in advance for any help with this.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
   .oVideo {
      width: 300px;
      height: 150px;
      background-color: #f00;
   }
</style>

<div class="oVideo">
</div>

<script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
      $('.oVideo').click(function () {
         var video = '<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/6TgyvSQlJtI?wmode=transparent&enablejsapi=1&rel=0&autohide=1&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen id="video"></iframe>';
         $('.oVideo').html(video);
      });
   });
</script>
```

**You just have to replace the background-color with your image.**

You can optimize this if you set the cursor of '.oVideo' with CSS to 'pointer'.

Comment: Thanks for replying ReeCube, but I think you have slightly misunderstood. Your code will put the video in the div but I also need to remove it on click of another element (anchor)

Comment: Sorry Ree tried too quickly to explain. What is happening is a div containing a youtube iframe embed then absolutely positioned over the top of this is another div 100% width 100% height that contains some content and a button. The button needs to hide the absolutely positioned div and on the same click play the video. There is a second button that needs to be able to stop the video and re-instate the absolutely positioned div. Currently I have code to stop and start the video (yt player api), and some JQuery to show and hide the div. The issue comes with merging the two.

Comment: Either move to raw js and have one click perform both operations or move fully to jquery and have the same happen for open/play and close/pause buttons. Hope this is clearer.

Comment: would work on its own but wont play and pause video, the same issue really, would need two click functions on one element.

Comment: you have to add them one after the other, first execute toggle then execute in the same function the play pause function